# ggpaired (boxplot) pairs incorrectly the data points

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, magrittr, ggpubr

I have a data frame for which I want to plot a boxplot to compare observations at different conditions.

But when I plot it, the lines that connect the data points across both boxplots are completely wrong:

```
if(!require(ggpubr)) {install.packages('ggpubr')} else {library(ggpubr)}

df = structure(list(y = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
               group = c("a", "a" , "b", "b", "c", "c"), 
               x = c("alpha", "beta", "alpha", "beta","alpha", "beta")),
          class = "data.frame", 
          row.names = c(NA, -6L))

ggpaired(data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y')
```

[image]

As you can see, the lines connecting the lines should be horizontal, as the values do not change across conditions; but instead, they connect randomly to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `id = "group"`.

```
ggpaired(data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y', id = "group")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What if the table didn't have a 'group' column? I thought the function would automatically pair by the order established in the df, but apparently that's not the case.

Comment: @HartRadev You can always create one. For example: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(group2 = 1:n())`